# How to pass context or any parameter in a static class in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, static-methods

I'm currently implementing pagination using [pagewise](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_pagewise) package. But to use the `pagecontroller`, I have to define a static controller and static future function that will connect to my api using http. My problem is, I also need the current user id as a parameter in my API request retrieved using provider. And I also need the BuildContext to show dialog box on API request return. Is it ok to save the id and context globally or outside the class just like the sample code below? Please teach me how to do this the correct way.

```
int id;
BuildContext currentContext;

class MyWidgetView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyWidgetViewState createState() => _MyWidgetViewState();
}

class _MyWidgetViewState extends State<MyWidgetView> {
  bool _empty = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    currentContext = context;
    id = Provider.of<User>(context, listen: false).id;
    this._pageLoadController.addListener(() {
      if (this._pageLoadController.noItemsFound) {
        setState(() {
          this._empty = this._pageLoadController.noItemsFound;
        });
      }
    });
  }

  final _pageLoadController = PagewiseLoadController(
      pageSize: PAGE_SIZE, pageFuture: (pageIndex) => getPage(pageIndex));
      
  static Future<List<page>> getPage(int pageIndex) async {
    final APIService _pageService = APIService();
    final pages = await _pageService.getPage(id: id);
    if (pages.error == false) {
      return pages.data;
    } else {
      dialogBox(
          title: 'Error',
          message: pages.errorMessage,
          context: currentContext,
          isModal: true,
          function: () => Navigator.pop(currentContext));
    }
  }
```

Comment: "I have to define a static controller and static future function" => Why?

Comment: @nvoig I cannot access the future getPage function from the _pageLoadController when it is not declared as static. Here is the error `Only static members can be accessed in initializers`

Comment: Then do it in the constructor. Or your initState method. You are looking at the wrong solution here. `static` is not a solution to your problem, it is just one *more* problem.

Comment: @nvoigt Can you give me an example on how to do that? I'm just following the pagewise plugin docs. They also using static.The error is coming from `final _pageLoadController = PagewiseLoadController()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That `static` is a rabbit hole you should not follow. Just don't make it `static` in the first place.

```
PagewiseLoadController _pageLoadController; 

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();

  _pageLoadController = PagewiseLoadController(pageSize: PAGE_SIZE, pageFuture: (pageIndex) => getPage(pageIndex));

  // rest of your method here    
}
```

Now your `getPage` method can be a normal, non-static class method.